# Not able to access server controls from code behind using FormView

Tags: asp.net

Curious question -
Why we cannot access a server control declared in the `<ItemTemplate>` of a `<asp:FormView>` control in code-behind?

Update -

Following is my markup:

[image]

I am unable to access ltrlInnerPanelTime control from code behind using FindControls() method as described here http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2006/07/03/145.aspx

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to achieve. those are server controls in itemtemplate with their native events to expose their states/life-cycle.

Comment: Thanks Palak. I now understand you cannot access server controls in code-behind if used within data-bound controls. You need to use FindControls() method. However, the issue which I am facing is mentioned in my post (updated) above.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to perform 3 FindControls. One for finding the **upInner** control inside **frmView**, another one for finding **lstMovieComments** inside **upInner**, and lastly, for finding **ltrInnerPanelTime** inside **upInner**.